# Remove View from memory

Tags: java, android, view, memory-leaks

I am using 4 views, defined in XMl, to perform an animation when the app starts, but after the animation is done, I would like to free the memory the bitmaps are using. How can I don this? As of now, when done, the views are set to GONE, but they still occupy memory.

Comment: try this view.setImageBitmap(null);

Comment: you have to detach them from the parent view

Answer (score 1):

You have to recycle bitmap and then you have to release memory allocated in the heap:

```
if (view.getBackground() != null) {
    try {
        view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
        ((BitmapDrawable) view.getBackground()).getBitmap().recycle();
        view.destroyDrawingCache();
        view.notifyAll();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, to free the memory.

```
bitmap.recycle();
bitmap = null;
```